# How to extract multiple groups from cell using pandas df.str.extract()

Tags: pandas

How can I get all the occurences of the patter as a list from the Pandas cell ? Is it possible?

```
name_pattern = r'([A]u?[-_\s]?[0-9]{2})'
df["Result"] = df["Name"].str.extract(name_pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Example Text:

Qui voluptates doloremque **A-12** veritatis dolor optio temporibus nobis fugit. Inventore excepturi quis nulla. Dolor ratione Z-99 optio doloribus voluptas veritatis voluptatem. Asperiores sed aperiam sint **A-99** voluptatem **A-66** exercitationem.

I would expect df["Result"] to be ["A-12","A-99","A-66"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
df["Result"] = (df["Name"].str.extractall(name_pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
                          .groupby(level=0)[0].apply(list))
```

which would result in the following `df`:

```
                                                Name              Result
0  Qui voluptates doloremque A-12 veritatis dolor...  [A-12, A-99, A-66]
```

Unfortunately, there is a [bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13382) that prevents this from working in 0.18.0 and 0.18.1 — it is fixed in the development version, and 0.19.0 will not have this problem. In the meantime, you can also do

```
df["Result"] = df["Name"].apply(lambda x: re.findall(name_pattern, x, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```